# ECharts Y Axis Axis Line not rendering?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

In this [Angular ECharts demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kuyb6g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.ts) the Y Axis Axis line is not rendering, and I have it configured like this:

```
       axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            type: 'solid',
            color: 'black',
            width: 4,
          },
        },
```

Thoughts?

## Update

I fixed the Stackblitz per the suggestion in the comments, so if you look at it you can see that it renders the Y Axis line when `show: true` is set.

Comment: Apparently you gave to set `axisLine.show: true`, but I don't know why, it should be the default value

Comment: Fun fact: looking on echarts site examples, none of their line charts show the y axis line! And in the options explorer, the value for `axisLine.show` is `"auto"`, which is not a (documented) valid value. Can it be such a long standing bug?

Comment: Hmmm ... You are right .... I'll file a bug report ... Good catch ...

Comment: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/18922